# "scibat facturos" in the prologue of Plautus' Amphitryon

Tags: vocabulary, plautus

In the prologue to Plautus' *Amphitryo*, lines 20-25, Mercurius says this:

> Pater huc me misit ad vos oratum meus,
>   tam etsi, pro imperio vobis quod dictum foret,
>   scibat **facturos**—quippe qui intellexerat
>   vereri vos se et metuere, ita ut æquom est Jovem—
>   verum profecto hoc petere me precario
>   a vobis jussit, leniter, dictis bonis.

I'm having trouble figuring out what *facturos* is doing here. I'm assuming it goes with the *vos* of *me misit ad vos oratum*, but what I can't for the life of me understand is what its *object* is. What does Jupiter know the audience members (that is, *vos*) are going to do?

Or am I misinterpreting something?

Answer (score 6):

The object is *pro imperio vobis quod dictum foret* (a relative clause in which the relative pronoun *quod* is postponed though logically belonging before *pro imperio*): literally, "even though he knew that you would do that which would be said to you in command".

[Riley](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:abo:phi,0119,001:1:prol) translates the first four lines thus: "My father has sent me hither to you to entreat, although, what should as his commands be enjoined on you, he knew that you would do, inasmuch as he knew full well that you venerate and fear himself, as is befitting Jupiter."

Comment: AH! So it's the punctuation in my edition that's screwing me up—it should be not "pro imperio vobis quod dictum foret, scibat facturos" but something like "pro imperio vobis, quod dictum foret scibat facturos"! Of course punctuation in millennia-old literature is a dicey thing to talk about, but thinking about it that way makes it much clearer for me. Thank you!

Comment: I think the punctuation makes sense, actually -- "that which will be said to you (vobis) in command (pro imperio), [that] he knows you will do". My answer was a little unclear as to the syntactic structure of the second line -- editing to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I was taking *pro imperio* as "instead of a command"—so with the parsing you offered, something like "instead of a command, which thing he knew you would do, he ordered [to be offered] lightly, in good words." In any case, punctuation aside, you have helped immensely.